# Copy selected text from PDF in PyQt5 QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I use `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets` to display a PDF and I'm trying to get the selected text.
Using `hasSelection()` and `selectedText()` works on HTML files, but it fails when the web view displays a PDF file. Any idea how to copy the selected text (apart from using CTRL+C)?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings, QWebEngineView

class Browser(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_selection(self):
        if self.hasSelection():
            print(self.selectedText())
        else:
            print('No text selected')

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self.menu = QMenu()
        get_selection = self.menu.addAction('Copy')
        get_selection.triggered.connect(self.get_selection)        
        self.menu.popup(event.globalPos())
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PDF Viewer")
        self.setGeometry(0, 28, 1000, 750)
        self.webView = QWebEngineView()
        self.webView = Browser()
        self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webView)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    win.webView.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile("d:/test.pdf"))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try changing self.selectedText() to self.page().selectedText()

Comment: It doesn't work either. For the record, I'm now using `keyboard.send("ctrl+c")` from the `keyboard` package  and `QApplication.clipboard().text()` to copy the selected text. Not really elegant, but it works.

Comment: Maybe try with [`triggerPageAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#triggerPageAction) with `QWebEnginePage.Copy`.